# why does the operator logic in Linq not match the results when the value is 0 or nothing in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, logical-operators

I'm Trying operator logic but in Linq not match the results when the value is 0 or nothing in VB.NET

`Let STATUS = If(BLC < 24 And PRSOBNET Is Nothing, "NEED TO PRODUCE", "")`

is there something wrong with my code? . Please Guide me.

```
Dim Cardex =
           From card In PurchaseDetails.Union(SalesDetails)
           Join mst In MasterItem On card.ITEM Equals mst.ITEM
           Group card By card.ITEM, mst.PRODUCTIONNAME, mst.BRAND, mst.PRSOBNET Into Group
           Let PIQ = (From x In Group Select x.PIQ).Sum
           Let SIQ = (From x In Group Select x.SIQ).Sum
           Let BLC = (PIQ) - (SIQ)
           Let STATUS = If(BLC < 24 And PRSOBNET Is Nothing, "NEED TO PRODUCE", "")
           Order By ITEM
           Select New ItemCards2 With {
    .ITEM = ITEM,
    .PRODUCTIONNAME = PRODUCTIONNAME,
    .BRAND = BRAND,
    .PRSOBNET = PRSOBNET,
    .PIQ = If(PIQ <> 0, PIQ, Nothing),
    .SIQ = If(SIQ <> 0, SIQ, Nothing),
    .BLC = If(BLC <> 0, BLC, Nothing),
    .STATUS = STATUS
 bindingSource = New BindingSource With {
    .DataSource = New BindingList(Of ItemCards2)(Cardex.ToList())
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource


Public Class ItemCards2
    Public Property ITEM As String
    Public Property PRODUCTIONNAME As String
    Public Property BRAND As String
    Public Property PRSOBNET As Integer?
    Public Property PIQ As Integer?
    Public Property SIQ As Integer?
    Public Property BLC As Integer?
    Public Property STATUS As String
End Class
```

[image: Result in datagridview]

Desired Result

| ITEM | PRODUCTIONNAME | BRAND | PRSOBNET | PIQ | SIQ | BLC | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | A | A1 | 20000 | 20 | 27 | -7 |  |
| 10000 | Z | Z1 |  | 23 |  | 23 | NEED TO PRODUCE |
| 2000 | B | B2 | 0 |  | 2 | -2 | NEED TO PRODUCE |

Comment: You might need the `AndAlso` operator instead of the `And` operator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator). `AndAlso` is equivalent to the `&&` operator in C# while the `And` is equivalent to `&` in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specifically want something to happen when a value is zero then you neeed to specify that. This:

```vb
Let STATUS = If(BLC < 24 And PRSOBNET Is Nothing, "NEED TO PRODUCE", "")
```

doesn't do that. You even put the solution in the title of your question:

> the value is 0 ***or*** nothing in VB.NET

You have "or" in your title but there's no `Or` in your code. You know what the logic is but you didn't implement it in code.

```vb
Let STATUS = If(BLC < 24 AndAlso (Not PRSOBNET.HasValue OrElse PRSOBNET.Value = 0), "NEED TO PRODUCE", "")
```

Note that I used `AndAlso` and `OrElse`, which are the short-circuiting Boolean operators. ALWAYS use them is preference to `And` and `Or` unless you specifically want to avoid short-circuiting, which should be fairly rare. In this specific case, using `And` rather than `AndAlso` would not affect the result but using `Or` rather than `OrElse` would generate a `NullReferenceException` in cases where `PRSOBNET.HasValue` was `False`, becaise it would still try to get `PRSOBNET.Value`. Short-circuiting ensures that the second operand is not evaluated if the the first operand is `True`.